# looping through array of DOM elements

Tags: javascript

This will probably be a simple question but is there a way to write this as a loop?

```
function playOne() {
    if (playOne) {
        document.getElementById("squareOne").innerHTML = '<img src="img/cross.png">';
    }

}

function playTwo() {
    if (playTwo) {
        document.getElementById("squareTwo").innerHTML = '<img src="img/cross.png">';
    }
}


function playThree() {
    if (playThree) {
        document.getElementById("squareThree").innerHTML = '<img src="img/cross.png">';
    }

}
```

Comment: could you be more specific? "Write this as a loop". What is the loop supposed to loop over? Do you want each of this function to be applied on whatever the loop is looping over?

Comment: Yes, and it would be simple since they all appear to have the same innerHTML. I would recommend having them share a class to make things a bit easier for you.

Comment: Those `if` statements make no sense. `playOne` is a function, so `if (playOne)` will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like?

```
let elems = {
  "squareOne": playOne,
  "squareTwo": playTwo,
  "squareThree": playThree,
}

for (var key in elems) {
  if(elems[key]) {
    document.getElementById(key).innerHTML = '<img src="img/cross.png">';
  }
}
```